# ReactJS, Hooks - How to setState after .map() function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to change state, with values from array. Example:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});
const test = [1, 2, 3];
        test.map((item, i) => {
          setState({ ...state, [`item-${i}`]: item });
        });
```

Current state is:

```
item-2: 3
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
item-0: 1,
item-1: 2,
item-2: 3
```

I've tried to do it in several ways (all looking similar), but the effect is the same :/ does anyone knows how to resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't set state in a loop. `const newState = { ...oldState }; test.forEach((item, i) => newState['item-' + i] = item); setState(newState);`

Comment: I hope your example is more complicated than an object filled with keys of `item-N`, because you're essentially duplicating the functionality of an array :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the state using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method like:

```
test.forEach((item, i) => {
   setState(state => ({...state, [`item-${i}`]: item}));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the functional version of set state and a reduce to accomplish this:

```
  setState(prevState => {
    return test.reduce((acc, next, i) => {
      return {
        ...acc,
        [`item-${i}`]: next
      },
    }, prevState);
  });
```

This has the advantage of doing it in a single call and is easier to read.